# WP categories as subdomains

Tags: wordpress, categories, subdomain

Need to transform a specific WP categories into subdomains.
i've tried "WP-subdomains" but not  working with 3.x . any visible solutions for that? with no problems or broken links!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP subdomain categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939323/wp-subdomain-categories)

Answer (score 0):

Alias and Mod-Rewrite in Apache Config would be an option.

Create vHost for the Category and place the rewriting .htaccess-File in the vHosts document root.

Comment: [an explanation](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/redirect-a-subdomain-with-apache-mod_rewrite-and-keep-the-url-in-the-address-bar/)